Why is it that when I hook OKHTP3 and read the response, it will be detected
I got the hook script from this website Project: okhttp3 Interceptor
I found that whenever I read the response string during application startup, the server will return a ‘token verification failure’, which means the server has discovered that I have used some methods to intercept it.
var source = responseBody.source();
console.log("reponse string", source.readUtf8());

I'm curious about how they did it, is it because they detected that the reading time had increased? Reading strings won't be very slow, right.
Please help me, thank you

May be the app uses okhttp3 in streaming mode. This is usually used for larger data and means that you are directly read from the incoming stream. Of course this means the stream can only be read once. If you use Frida to read it the stream is gone. Therefore it is important to check the app you want to hook how thy use okhttp3. May be it is better to not hook okhttp3 but the code that processes the response body.
